# How to get the journal mode of my sqlite db

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

How can I get the journal mode of my sqlite db using sqlalchemy?

```
@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    print "PRAGMA start"
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    print cursor.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;")
    print cursor.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode;")
    cursor.close()
    print "PRAGMA end"
```

Can I use cursor object? I am not sure how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `PRAGMA journal_mode` will result in one row with one column containing the journal mode, similar to if you did `SELECT "somevalue"`. You should be able to retrieve it the same way you would retrieve the result of a SELECT query.

Comment: Can you give an example if possible?